# flipboard first screen animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Does anyone knows how to build a animation like the **flipboard** first screen animation? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/03/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-3-splash-screen/) will help you

Comment: thanks but i want to know **flipboard first screen animation concept**

Comment: You can animate the splash screen using the UIViewAnimations. Pls go through them.